# Solr Exclusion of Fields from fl

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/browse&q=foo&omitNorms=%22true%22&start=0&wt=json&omitHeader=true
```

It will return all fields present in solr. But I want to exclude one or two fields from the field list. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. Check [SOLR-3191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3191)
If you specify the fields in the request handler as defaults so that you don't have to pass them